# select identical entries in two pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. (a,b,c,d ) and (i,j,k) are the name columns dataframes

```
df1 =

  a  b  c  d
  0  1  2  3
  0  1  2  3
  0  1  2  3

df2 =

  i  j  k  
  0  1  2  
  0  1  2  
  0  1  2
```

I want to select the entries that df1 is df2
I want to obtain

```
 df1=   

  a  b  c  
  0  1  2  
  0  1  2  
  0  1  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for compare `df1` with each column of `df2`:

```
dfs = []
for i in range(len(df2.columns)):
    df = df1.isin(df2.iloc[:,i])
    dfs.append(df)
```

Then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all mask together:

```
mask = pd.concat(dfs).groupby(level=0).sum()
print (mask)
      a     b     c      d
0  True  True  True  False
1  True  True  True  False
2  True  True  True  False
```

Apply [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df1.ix[:, mask.all()])
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  0  1  2
2  0  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a column-wise comparison would give the desired result:

```
df1 = df1[(df1.a == df2.i) & (df1.b == df2.j) & (df1.c == df2.k)][['a','b','c']]
```

You get only those rows from `df1` where the values of the first three columns are identical to those of `df2`.

Then you just select the rows `'a','b','c'` from `df1`.

Comment: thanks @Khris , I do not know in advance the columns, I try to do it automatically